# Changing value in data structure

Tags: json, jinja2

I have a JSON structure where I need to substitute the value if a key named `secured` is set to the value `1`. I'm doing this in jinja. An example of the JSON is this:

```
{
   "OperatingSystems":{
      "Ubuntu":{
         "Cores":{
            "value":"4",
            "secured":0
         },
         "Memory":{
            "value":"8",
            "secured":0
         },
         "Storage":{
            "value":"500",
            "secured":0
         },
         "Accounts":{
            "Test":{
               "Name":{
                  "value":"aabb",
                  "secured":0
               },
               "Password":{
                  "value":"1231",
                  "secured":1
               }
            }
         },
         "Testttt":{
            "Cores":{
               "value":"4",
               "secured":0
            },
            "Memory":{
               "value":"8",
               "secured":0
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "Services":{
      "AVX-AADDSS":{
         "Accounts":{
            "AWX":{
               "Admin":{
                  "value":"admin",
                  "secured":0
               },
               "Password":{
                  "value":"1231",
                  "secured":1
               }
            },
            "lawip":{
               "Name":{
                  "value":"admin",
                  "secured":0
               },
               "Password":{
                  "value":"33111",
                  "secured":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The JSON is dynamic. And when for example the "OperationgSystems.Ubuntu.Accounts.Test.Password" has the `secured` property set to `1` I want to change the `value` property `1231` to `abc`.

I have tried the following but this just outputs the same format and exact same data as the input. Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

```
{%- macro build_model(data, model_path) %}
    {%- for key, value in data.items() %}
        {%- if value is mapping %}
            {%- set _ = model_path.update({key: {}}) -%}
            {{ build_model(value, model_path[key]) }}
        {%- else %}
            {%- if value is mapping and 'secured' in value and value['secured'] == 1 %}
                {%- set _ = model_path.update({key: 'abc'}) -%}
            {%- elif value is mapping and 'value' in value %}
                {%- set _ = model_path.update({key: value['value']}) -%}
            {%- else %}
                {%- set _ = model_path.update({key: value}) -%}
            {%- endif %}
        {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}

{%- set inventory_model = {} %}
{{ build_model(props, inventory_model) }}

{{ inventory_model | tojson(indent=4) }}
```